# определение симетричности числа

Tags: java

Условие: дается 4-х значное число, определить является ли оно симетричным(пример симетричности: 2002,1551,...); если симетрично - вывести 1, в противном случае вывести любое другое число. Число может иметь меньше чем 4 цифры, тогда подразумевается что слева дописываются нули.
пример:
input : 2002
output: 1

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int input = in.nextInt();
      int a = input/1000;
      int b = (input/100)%10;
      int c = (input/10)%100;
      int d = input%1000;
      if (a==d&b==c) {
       System.out.println(1);
      }else {
       System.out.println(37);
      }
     }
    }
```

это мое решение задания. Вопрос, что я мог не учесть т.к. при проверке 9 теста ответ не верный (входные данные тестов неизвестны, но не противоречат условию)

Comment: переведите в строку и сравните поиндексно

Comment: лучше как раз делить на 10. Перевод в строку - не самая быстрая операция, тем более потом придется еще и в массив чаров в лучшем случае... Просто не нужно привязываться к разрядности числа. Делите в цикле число, цифры складывайте в коллекцию. А потом перебирайте коллекцию с двух сторон и сравнивайте полученные ранее числа.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович так как берется из Scanner, то с точностью до наоборот

Comment: По условию задачи написано, что дано число... Из этого и исхожу.

Comment: Проходит? https://ideone.com/hTBs1l

Comment: число дано, но входные данные считываются сканером; про коллекцию я еще не читал, код написан исходя из моих знаний, а чем плохо сравнение чисел в моём "if"?

Comment: `int d = input%10;` - цифра в разряде единиц

Comment: `int c = (input/10)%10;` - цифра в разряде десятков

Comment: `int b = (input/100)%10;` - цифра в разряде сотен и так далее

Comment: 2112 выводит 37. Отлаживайте.

Comment: оказался неправ с нулями в "c" и "d", правка от  @Igor прошла все тесты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int c = (input/10)%100;
int d = input%1000;
```

Ошибка здесь. Должно быть `% 10` в обоих случаях. Странно, что восемь тестов вообще прошли.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = 123443210;
    String str = Long.toString(x);
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
    if (str.length() % 2 != 0) {
        s1.append("0");
    }
    s1.append(str.substring(0, str.length() / 2));
    s2.append(str.substring(str.length() / 2)).reverse();

    if (s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()))
        System.out.println("1");
    else System.out.println("0");
}
```

}

Comment: а почему, если длина нечетная, то выводить 0? Если будет число 101 - оно симметрично само себе. Так что тут не совсем правильно

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;



/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class Symmetry2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int input = in.nextInt();
      int units = input % 10; // еденицы
      int n = input / 10; 
      int tens = n % 10;  // десятки
      n = n / 10; 
      int hundreds = n % 10;  // сотни 
      n = n / 10; 
      int thousands = n % 10; // тысячи

      /*убеждаемся что правильно ввели*/
      System.out.println( "thousands = "+ thousands +" hundreds = "+hundreds+" tens= "+tens+" units = "+units);

      // выводим результат
      if (thousands!=units||tens!=hundreds) {
          System.out.println(37);
      }else {
          System.out.println(1);
      }
    }
}
```