# Задача Sum of digits. Цифр катастрофически не хватает

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток дамы и господа. Решаю задачи, на популярном ресурсе, натолкнулся на ту которая скоро сведет меня с ума. Задача состоит в том чтобы вывести сумму цифр какого-то числа. Вот код :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        sumOfDigits(2030);
    }

}
public static int sumOfDigits(int x){
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    do {                  // в цикле пытаюсь записать цифры в список
        list.add(x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
    }
    while (x/10 > 0);

    for (Integer element : list){  //тут проверяю ,
        System.out.println(element); // какие цифры попали в список
    }
    int result = 0 ;         // получаю
    for (int element : list){ // сумму
        result += element;   // цифр
    }

   return result;
}
```

}

Постарался прокомментировать свои шаги во втором методе. Итак, суть проблемы в том что при проверке , какие цифры попали в список, не хватает первой цифры. Внимание! Если меняю местами строки в цикле do while , не хватает последней цифры. Не могу понять что именно я сделал не так. Прошу конструктивной критики и решения проблемы.
На консоль выводит сумму всех цифр кроме той которой не хватает , в данном случае первой цифры заданного числа. Ожидаю, естественно , что выведет сумму всех цифр.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768477

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767821

Comment: фрактальное сгущение вопросов о сумме цифр числа

Comment: это все замечательно, но у него все решение через массивы, а у меня чуть иначе, и я ни капли не представляю как его решение может мне помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Его решение" может Вам помочь тем, что в нем есть правильный цикл `while` :).

```
while (x > 0) {
    list.add(x % 10);
    x = x / 10;
}
```

Comment: Это гениально. Спасибо. Стоит быть внимательней